# Access data property of component in Vuex store

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I have a component with data as:

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      allItems: [],
      orderItems: {},
      itemAdded: [],
    };
  },
```

I want to access the `itemAdded` array data which is present in the local component in the Vuex `store.js` file.
Is there anyway to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't access component data from vuex, what you can do is pass the data as the payload when dispatching a vuex action.

for example, your vuex action:

```js
actions: {
  doSomething(context, itemAdded) {
    // Do something with itemAdded
  }
}
```

and dispatch the action from your component:

```js
this.$store.dispatch('doSomething', this.itemAdded);
```

If you want to change `itemAdded` value on the component from the vuex action, you can return the value like this:

```js
actions: {
  doSomething(context, itemAdded) {
    // Do something with itemAdded
    return itemAdded;
  }
}
```

and on your component:

```js
// Need to use await since dispatch return a promise, you can also use `.then`
this.itemAdded = await this.$store.dispatch('doSomething', this.itemAdded);
```

Keep in mind that Vuex is a state management, and vuex action should do an action that's related to a state, not a place to store a 'reusable function'. I can't think of any case why would you want to return the edited value from the action, but if you think it makes sense / it's related to state, then you can do it this way.

Comment: But will itemAdded change if I change it in store.js

Comment: You will hold another data in vuex. You will pass itemAdded to vuex mutations or actions and play with it in your vuex. So itemAdded will be same but you can put it in your vuex store and use it whenever or wherever you want to.

Comment: No it wont change the value on the component, you can return the changed value from the vuex action and assign in to the component value, check my edit for example.